# Cannot access admin panel

Tags: admin, login

I have been working on my site through MAMP and with a localhost. I have *not* uploaded my site online yet.

I have worked in it for weeks accessing through the MAMP start page and then typing http://localhost:8888 on my browser.

Well, after a long night I woke up the next day and tried to log in as always. When I do it, my site appears on the browser but I cannot edit a thing. I mean, there is no way I can enter the admin panel, there are no tabs, no WP icon, not even the little EDIT squares at the end of every post or page where I clicked and it took me to the admin panel and dashboard.

I can navigate through the site, it works perfectly, It looks as if it was online, but simply I cannot edit anything.

I tried to remember what I did differently from the other days, and the only thing I came up with is that I updated a galleria plugin and I activated a new contact plugin widget.
As I read in the forums I took all the plugins from my wp-content folder inside the WordPress folder but that did not solve the problem. I tried replacing the entire WordPress folder for a fresh download, the site looks funny no photos but still cannot access to the admin panel. I have no code or programming experience and am I new to WordPress.
I am stuck with a dead line and no idea on what to do!

Comment: No need to shout...

Comment: Sorry I did not realize I did.I apologize!

Comment: Try using localhost/wp-login.php not just localhost/wp-login. I have the same problem but am not sure why its happening either until I figure it out this was my solution.

Answer (score 3):

The way you describe it, it sounds as if WordPress was installed to your root directory. That however doesn't explain why http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/ doesn't work, unless you renamed the directory..? Try accessing http://localhost:8888/wp-login.php

Comment: THANKS but it comes back as: The requested URL /wp-login.php was not found on this server.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to log in using the following url once logged in?

http://localhost:8888/wp-admin

The reason your photos don't appear anymore is that they are not in the new install you've made. I hope that you did not erased the first install, because your medias are stored inside the wordpress/wp-content/uploads directory.

Comment: Thanks I have never logged in using a url I have always done it through the MAMP start page and then typing http://localhost:8888 on my browser. I have already st the photos back, that is not the proble. The issue is I don know how to access the admin panel

Comment: Used your suggestion and got"

Comment: used your suggestion and got: The requested URL /wp-admin was not found on this server.

Comment: 3.3.1 the latest

Comment: If you did not change the default theme, and if you are indeed logged in, you should see a column on the right of the home page, with "Archives" and "Meta" headers. Normally, there should be a "Site Admin" link. Click on that link and you will get to the dashboard. If this doesn't work, then you have a problem with your install. It is not normal (not default behaviour) that you cannot access the wp-admin directory.

Answer (score 1):

it's a long shot but i think you forgot to type the folder name of you wordpress installation...

Are you sure you access your website directly on http:/localhost:8888/ ? because that means you installed your website on your local Sites folder root. If you access the website on http://localhost:8888/foldername/ than you should be able to access the wordpress admin on http://localhost:8888/foldername/wp-admin

Comment: It comes back as:

Comment: it comes back as: The requested URL /foldername/wp-admin was not found on this server.

Comment: DEAR TALBATZ when I login that way I do see my site working as if it were online, but I cannot edit anything, I cannot see the login tab or WP icon or the dashboard :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this going to help much, but try the command line and `find wp-admin` then type that location into the browser.